# how to use Bluetooth Obex OPP using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, obex

I am using Xamarin to develop an android App, which should be able to share file over Bluetooth using OPP OBject EXchange protocol.

I am able to successfully send file using CSharp .Net Project with InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth and InTheHand.Net.Personal libraries.
But same libraries are unable to be used with Xamarin Mobile based Project.
Can any one help with any other Library which I can use to share file over OBEX protocol in my Xamarin based project.

Comment: unfortunately we don't recommend libraries here

Comment: Do you use this Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin? https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

Comment: I need classic bluetooth with support of Obex Push Profile. LE is not something I want in this requirement.